# Почему график по датам строится некорректно

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, seaborn

Допустим у меня есть датасет где даты. Я получаю кол-во через value_counts, в итоге получаю такие серии:

[image: Данные]

Почему когда хочу построить график через метод dataframe, у меня получается следующая ситуация:

[image: Некорректный график]

А если через seaborn то получается вот такая ситуация:

[image: Ожидаемый график]

Возникает вопрос: почему это происходит, и как сделать график который получается с помощью seabron за счет методов dataframe?

Comment: Произведите сортировку по столбцу `year` в качестве индекса

Comment: @Dareten Отлично, сработало, спасибо. Полагаю seaborn сортирует сразу по индексу в таком случае

Answer (score 3):

У вас просто не отсортирован массив по дате. Seaborn делает это под капотом, потому что он user-friendly

Comment: @strawdog, ты уверен? Очень похоже на ответ.

Comment: @strawdog, точно ответ, с учётом комментариев под вопросом.

Comment: 1. @Qwertiy комментарию под вопросом - сутки. Этому "ответу", да еще и от другого пользователя - 5 часов. 2. Комментарий содержит конкретное решение. Этот "ответ" - нет.

Comment: 1. Ответы надо писать в ответах, а не в комментариях - только недавно [тема на мете](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9441/178988) про это же была. 2. Да вроде по ответу понятно, что предлагается отсортировать.

Comment: Так может посоветовать автору комментария оформить его как ответ? А не давать "ответ" по мотивам комментария другого пользователя? Хотя, кто я такой, чтобы спорить с модератором, тем более, что "недавно тема на мете была как раз про это".

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97923/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-strawdog).